Lee's Smooth Manifolds 10-12
I am trying to solve the first direction from the following exercise from Lee's Smooth Manifolds.

Exercise 10-12 Let $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ and $\tilde{\pi}: \widetilde{E} \rightarrow M$ be two smooth rank- $k$ vector bundles over a smooth manifold $M$ with or without boundary. Suppose $\left\{U_\alpha\right\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is an open cover of $M$ such that both $E$ and $\widetilde{E}$ admit smooth local trivializations over each $U_\alpha$. Let $\left\{\tau_{\alpha \beta}\right\}$ and $\left\{\tilde{\tau}_{\alpha \beta}\right\}$ denote the transition functions determined by the given local trivializations of $E$ and $\widetilde{E}$, respectively. Show that $E$ and $\widetilde{E}$ are smoothly isomorphic over $M$ if and only if for each $\alpha \in A$ there exists a smooth map $\sigma_\alpha: U_\alpha \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(k, \mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
\tilde{\tau}_{\alpha \beta}(p)=\sigma_\alpha(p) \tau_{\alpha \beta}(p) \sigma_\beta(p)^{-1}, \quad p \in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta .
$$


My attempt for the first direction:
Fix $U_\alpha$. Then there exist local trivializations
$$
U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k \stackrel{\Phi}{\leftarrow} E \quad \tilde{E} \stackrel{\Psi}{\rightarrow} U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k
$$
Since $F:E\to \tilde E$ is a smooth homomorphism, its restriction over the fibers is linear, so we can define the map.
$$\sigma_\alpha(p) = \Psi\circ \left.F\right|_p \circ \Phi^{-1}.$$
Ny questions are:

Did I create the correct map $\sigma_\alpha$
How can I show that $\tilde{\tau}_{\alpha \beta}(p)=\sigma_\alpha(p) \tau_{\alpha \beta}(p) \sigma_\beta(p)^{-1}, \quad p \in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta $?


Let me elaborate a bit more on what you wrote...

We'll use the notation $E_x := \pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ and $\tilde{E}_x := \tilde{\pi}^{-1}(\{x\})$.

A bundle morphism between two vector bundles $E$ and $\tilde{E}$ is a smooth map $F : E \rightarrow \tilde{E}$ satisfying two conditions:



$\tilde{\pi} \circ F = \pi$, and

for every $x \in M$, the map $F_x : E_x \rightarrow \tilde{E}_x$ is linear.



For $U_\alpha$ in our set, we'll denote our local trivializations by $\varphi_\alpha : U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ and $\tilde{\varphi}_\alpha : U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \tilde{\pi}^{-1}(U_\alpha)$. As an abuse of notation, we'll write
$$ \varphi_{\alpha \beta} : (U_\alpha \cap U_\beta) \times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow (U_\alpha \cap U_\beta) \times \mathbb{R}^k, \ \ \varphi_{\alpha \beta} := (\varphi_{\alpha})^{-1} \circ \varphi_\beta.$$

The transition maps $\{\tau_{\alpha \beta}\}_{\alpha, \beta}$ are smooth maps given by
$$ \tau_{\alpha \beta} : U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \rightarrow \text{GL}(k, \mathbb{R}),  \ \ \varphi_{\alpha \beta}(x,v) = (x, \tau_{\alpha \beta}v).$$
where
$$ (\varphi_\beta)^{-1} \circ \varphi_\alpha : (U_\alpha \cap U_\beta) \times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow (U_\alpha \cap U_\beta) \times \mathbb{R}^k, \ \ $$


Let's now talk about the implication. For a given $\alpha$, we can define a map $F_\alpha : \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ by restricting $F$. We now get an induced map
$$ \hat{F}_\alpha : U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k, \ \ \hat{F}_\alpha := (\tilde{\varphi}_\alpha)^{-1} \circ F_\alpha \circ \varphi_\alpha.$$
Observe that
$$\tilde{\pi} \circ \tilde{\varphi}_\alpha \circ \hat{F}_\alpha(x,v) = x,$$
so $\hat{F}_\alpha(x,v) = (x, \sigma_\alpha(x)v)$. Furthermore, $\sigma_\alpha(x)$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^k$.
Next, we observe that
$$ \hat{F}_\alpha \circ \varphi_{\alpha \beta} \circ (\hat{F}_\beta)^{-1} = (\tilde{\varphi}_\alpha)^{-1} \circ F_\alpha \circ \varphi_\alpha \circ (\varphi_\alpha)^{-1} \circ \varphi_\beta \circ \varphi_\beta \circ (F_\beta)^{-1} \circ \tilde{\varphi}_\beta \\ = (\tilde{\varphi}_\alpha)^{-1} \circ F_\alpha \circ (F_\beta)^{-1} \circ \tilde{\varphi}_\beta .$$
Restricting to $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$, we have that $F_\alpha = F_\beta$, so the middle part cancels. Furthermore, they all leave the first coordinate fixed. Equality then implies that
$$ \sigma_\alpha(x) \tau_{\alpha \beta} \sigma_\beta(x)^{-1} = \tilde{\tau}_{\alpha \beta}.$$
This argument mostly reverses in the following sense. Supposing we have such a $\sigma_\alpha$, we can define $\hat{F}_\alpha$ by
$$\hat{F}_\alpha : U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k, \ \ \hat{F}_\alpha(x,v) := (x, \sigma_\alpha(x)v).$$
From this, we can define $F_\alpha$ by
$$F_\alpha : \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \rightarrow \tilde{\pi}^{-1}(U_\alpha), \ \ F_\alpha := \tilde{\varphi}_\alpha \circ \hat{F}_\alpha \circ (\varphi_\alpha)^{-1}.$$
Finally, let $F : E \rightarrow \tilde{E}$ be defined by $F(v) = F_\alpha(v)$ if $v \in \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$. The only thing we need to check is that this is well-defined, as it will be invertible by construction. Suppose $v \in \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta)$. Then
$$F_\beta^{-1} \circ F_\alpha(v) = \varphi_\beta \circ (\hat{F}_\beta)^{-1} \circ \tilde{\varphi}_{\beta \alpha} \circ \hat{F}_\alpha \circ (\varphi_\alpha)^{-1}(v).$$
By assumption,
$$(\hat{F}_\beta)^{-1} \circ \tilde{\varphi}_{\beta \alpha} \circ \hat{F}_\alpha(x,v) = (x, \sigma_\beta^{-1}(x) \tilde{\tau}_{\beta \alpha} \sigma_\alpha(x)v) = (x, \tau_{\beta \alpha}v) = (\varphi_\beta)^{-1} \circ \varphi_\alpha(x,v).$$
Thus
$$F_\beta^{-1} \circ F_\alpha(v) = v \implies F_\alpha(v) = F_\beta(v).$$
